# how to get the name of the feature being installed using wix managed bootstrapper ui

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I am using WiX to install a executable and I have used ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost for CustomUI.

Is it possible to get the name of the feature being installed at the time of installation ?

If possible then how can we get the name of the feature ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Features aren't installed one after another. For example if 3 features are being installed, each with 10 files then the InstallFiles action will install all 30 files at the same time. Same thing with registry entries. So you can't display a UI that says "Installing Feature1" and then later on "Installing Feature2" because that doesn't happen. All you can know is that some list of features are being installed. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW for your reply.how can we get the list of features which are being installed and if possible can we also get their state (installed successfully/failed)  ?

Comment: I'll consolidate some things into some kind of answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features aren't installed one after another. For example if 3 features are being installed, each with 10 files then the InstallFiles action will install all 30 files at the same time. Same thing with registry entries. So you can't display a UI that says "Installing Feature1" and then later on "Installing Feature2" because that doesn't happen. All you can know is that some list of features are being installed.

Your comment asks about finding out whether a feature installed successfully or not. This issue never comes up - there are never some features that install and others that fail. An MSI install is a transaction and it either all works or fails and rolls back and deletes changes it made so that the system is restored to its previous state.

It's not clear why the list of features is so important to display. If you use the MSI's internal UI there is a feature selection dialog where the user selects which features are to be installed; if you use the Burn UI the same thing is available, so the user can see what features have been chosen.

Inside the MSI the list of features being installed (after they've been selected) is in the ADDLOCAL property, but that's the internal name. It could be used to display a list of the features that were installed at the end, but again by definition what was chosen is installed otherwise the install would have rolled back entirely.  I don't believe I've ever seen an install where the list of MSI features installed is displayed at the end - it's redundant info. It would be useful to know the scenario you have, or what problem you're trying to solve, and if you believe that you need to display a list because some might install and others might fail then there is no point, as I have said.

Comment: Thanks PhilDW for your comments.It helped me